# Я хочу создать, коментарии на python Django, но получилась ошибка :(

Tags: python, django

HTML:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{article.art_title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>{{article.art_title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{article.art_text}}</h2>
    <em>{{article.pub_date}}</em>
    <hr>
    <h1>Test</h1>


    <hr>

<form action="{% url 'articles:leave_comment' article.id %}" method="POST">

  {% csrf_token %}

      <input id="pols" type="text" required placeholder="Ваше имя" name="polename"><br>
      <textarea id="gols" name="textcomment" required placeholder="Текст комментария" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
      <button type="submit">Оставить комментарий</button>

    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

PYTHON DJANGO:

```py
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Article

def index(request):
  latest_articles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
  return render(request, 'articles/list.html', {'latest_articles_list': latest_articles_list})

def detail(request, article_id):
 try:
  a = Article.objects.get( id = article_id )
 except:
  raise Http404("Статья не найдена!")

  return render(request, 'articles/detail.html', {'article': a})

def leave_comment(request, article_id):
    try:
        a = Article.objects.get( id = article_id )
    except:
            raise Http404("Статья.. Не найдена!")

    a.comment_set.create(autor_name = request.POST['polename'], comment_text = request.POST['textcomment'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('articles:detail', args = (a.id,)) )
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте в сам вопрос вашу ошибку, для этого нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом